# Navigation between screens breaks in Expo app after compilation

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo

I've just finished building an Expo app along with TypeScript. Everything seems to be okay in the live testing mode, but, after compiling the app into a standalone app (for Android at least, haven't tried for ios), the navigation between the screens seems to be broken. I cannot even go past the first screen (when I press on the next button, the app just crashes immediately), although I know all screens are doing just fine in isolation. I am using Expo version 4.4.1, under the managed workflow.

This is my NavigationStack.tsx:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import EntireMapScreen from '../app/screens/EntireMapScreen';
import CardFormScreen from '../app/screens/CardFormScreen';
import ChooseOfferScreen from '../app/screens/ChooseOfferScreen';
import DecisionScreen from '../app/screens/DecisionScreen';
const screens = {
Decision: {
screen: DecisionScreen
    },
ChooseOffer: {
screen: ChooseOfferScreen
    },
Payment: {
screen: CardFormScreen
    },
EntireMap: {
screen: EntireMapScreen
    }
}
const navigationStack = createStackNavigator(screens, {
defaultNavigationOptions: {
headerShown: false
    }
});
export default createAppContainer(navigationStack);
```

The way one file generally looks like is this (DecisionScreen.tsx):

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationStackProp, NavigationStackScreenProps } from "react-navigation-stack";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { NavigationInjectedProps, withNavigation } from "react-navigation";
/**
 * An extremly simple non-GUI screen, which decides if the user should pay again for the app
 * or if the app can simply be used.
 */
class DecisionScreen extends React.Component<NavigationInjectedProps, {
form: {
status: {
cvc: string,
expiry: string,
name: string,
number: string
        },
valid: boolean,
values: {
cvc: string,
expiry: string,
name: string,
number: string,
type: string
        }
    },
fontsLoaded: boolean,
waitingServerResponse: boolean,
showError: boolean // if true, we know something went wrong billing the user with 
// the currently inserted details
}> {
keyboardDidHideListener: any;
constructor(props: any) {
super(props);
this.state = {
form: {
status: {
cvc: "incomplete",
expiry: "incomplete",
name: "incomplete",
number: "incomplete"
                },
valid: false,
values: {
cvc: "",
expiry: "",
name: "",
number: "",
type: ""
                }
            },
fontsLoaded: false,
waitingServerResponse: false,
showError: false
        };
    }
makeDecision = async (trial: number) => {

...
    }
render = () => <></>;
componentDidMount = () => {
this.makeDecision(1);
    }
}
export default withNavigation(DecisionScreen);
```

I've lost the last 6 hours or so in finding a similar situation on the internet. The best I could find was this article: https://dev.to/andreasbergqvist/react-navigation-with-typescript-29ka, which did not solve the issue. Does anybody know how I could be solving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was finally due to the fact there was a promise in an async function which did not resolve until the moment of being called later on as an undefined. Therefore, the solution was to simply add an await statement next to that promise.